# Should I create extra functions to make my code testable?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I am creating an application which depending on the day that it runs, it creates different reports.

So if it is  Monday @ 1am,  It will create a weekly report, if it is the 1st of the month @ 1.30am, it will create a monthly report.

My initial approach uses one class.  It has a property which is an array, that maps each report to a function. The calling script calls the run() method on the class, which in turn loops through the array and calls the function for each report.

How do I test this?  I want to have a decent suite of unit tests to cover the calculations.

Do I create two functions for each report?  One which grabs the data from the DB, and another to do the calculations (which would be testable via params).  This seems long winded though!  I would have 24 functions instead of 12.

Confused about the best way to do this.

Thanks!

EDIT: To clarify,  the script is run by a cron job, at those specific times mentioned above.  I have already tested the time checking code (it sets the run mode depending on time) by using Reflection.  I am considering taking the date out of the class altogether, and letting the calling script define which reports are being run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to test your code, you always find yourself in these type of situations: a class has a lot of private functions that I'd like to test.

What you call "extra" functions, they're not. It's just that if you want to be able to test some code, it normally must be accessible from a test, and probably in the form of a separate class.

This is the structure I'd follow:

```
class ReportGenerator
{
    private $calculator;

    public function __construct(ReportCalculator $calculator)
    {
        $this->calculator = $calculator;
    }

    public function generate()
    {
         $calculation_method = $this->computeCalculationMethod();
         return $this->calculator->$calculation_method();
    }

    private function computeCalculationMethod()
    {
         switch ($week_day) {
             ...
         }
         return $method;
    }
}

class ReportCalculator
{
     public function calculation1()
     {

     }

     public function calculationN()
     {

     } 
}
```

So the calculations are done using a class that can be easily tested.

For testing that the correct method is being called for each week day, you inject a mock of the ReportCalculator class when creating the ReportGenerator in the test and check that the correct call is being made for each case.

You must also get control over the current week day in the test. That can be done by using a DateProvider class that you can also mock, or by using some other trick like namespace overriding.

Answer (score 1):

While calculating the current date is trivial, i'd break it out of your function, so you can test different values for the date without changing your code.

2 options come to mind.

1. Make it a parameter of the function.  So, you can test it by calling your function with different values.  That way, don't have to wait until specific times to test your code.  Then, do unit tests by calling your main code with different date parameters.

or

2. Make the date logic a separate function, so you can test that date logic separately.  Then, just have your function call the date logic code.